# How to display an image returned as a bytes in browser without prompting download?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I have written the following PHP function but still get the prompt to download the file:

```
function navigateToBytes($contentType, $bytes){
  header('Content-Type: ' .$contentType); 
  //header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); // UPDATE: as pointed out this is not needed, though it does not solve the problem
  header('Content-Length: '.strlen($bytes));
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  echo $bytes;
}
```

An example of calling the function:

```
navigateToBytes('image/jpeg', $bytes); // UPDATE: turns out this does work, using image/tiff for tiff images is when the browser does not display the image
```

where $bytes are the bytes as read from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies all - turns out I was having the problem because the images I was testing were TIFF's (with the Content-Type correctly set to image/tiff) when I used a JPEG the browser would display the image!

Ultimately it is up to the browser to decide whether it can display the Content-Type you are sending.

For the record the only headers I needed to change was

```
Content-Type,
```

I should set

```
Content-Length
```

too unless I set

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the HTTP header "`Content-Disposition: Inline`", however some browsers may try to save the user from seeing binary data.  Here is a random blog article on that HTTP header:

http://dotanything.wordpress.com/2008/05/30/content-disposition-attachment-vs-inline/

Comment: The article questions the use of Content-Disposition header but offers no answers, some comments attempt to..

Answer (score 0):

That seems like correct behavior to me.  The browser is a viewport for humans to view things in.  Humans, by and large, don't want to view binary data.  What do you think should happen?

Random Advice: If there's a site that's doing what you want to do, use curl to sniff the headers they're sending.

```
curl -I http://example.com/path/to/binary/file/that/displays/in/browser
```

and then use the exact same headers in your own script.

Comment: The problem is when you have dynamic content - for example I do do not know what the link will fetch - it could be a jpeg, tiff or pdf - I look at the bytes at runtime determine the file type then return it to the browser - a pdf i want the client to download so send the "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf" header which forces the download, however with images I would rather they are just displayed - of course the binary is not displayed the image should be rendered as it always is in browser.

Comment: Im aware I can look at headers from other sites - but I cannot find such as site that embeds the image data - the image is always in an image tag.

Comment: What is point of "Content-Type: image/jpeg"  if the file is always downloaded?? I may as well use: "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.jpg"

Comment: Gee, you're right, how could anyone not have noticed in 15 years ;)  The Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary is "winning".  If you want the image to be displayed in the browser leave it out.  Look at the headers that every other website uses.  curl -I http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo27.png. It's clear you're after something we're not understanding, but it's also clear you have a few fundamental disconnects with how the web works.

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear: I want the image sent as bytes to be displayed without being prompted to download it, removing Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary has no change..

Answer (score 0):

As a start, get rid of things that do not exist in HTTP (Content-Transfer-Encoding).

Then get an HTTP tracing tool, such as the Live HTTP headers plugin for Firefox, and compare "your" headers with those received for a working image.

In doubt, post the HTTP trace here.

Comment: There is no doubt - I already use Live HTTP Headers - I know what is being sent - It is working the problem is im asked to download the image - but I just want to display it - if you know of such an example where an image is returned as bytes rather than in a HTML page please let me know :)